# How to start webkitSpeechRecognition on CefSharp browser for wpf

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, cefsharp, webkitspeechrecognition

I've created a javascript page and when I load that page inside chrome browser I am able to start webkitSpeechRecognition. However when I call that url with CefSharp browser for winform, It does not start the webkitSpeechRecognition.

Could you please advise me what could be the possible reason?

Here is the code snippet I call on button click.

```
function startWebKit() {

  if (window.hasOwnProperty('webkitSpeechRecognition')) {


    var recognition = new window.webkitSpeechRecognition();
    var recognizing = false;

    recognition.onstart = function () {
      recognizing = true;
    };

    recognition.onend = function () {
      recognizing = false;
    };

    recognition.onerror = function (event) {
      recognizing = false;
    };

    try {
      recognition.start();
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error);
    }

    if (recognizing) {
      // Do stuff
    }
  }
}
```

TIA

Comment: https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=15623&p=36791